# Insert data with SPARQL not committed in a dataset Jena ARQ

Tags: java, sparql, jena, ontology, owl-api

I would like to insert a new class in my Jena model ('modelInput) with a SPARQL Query and Jena ARQ.
I'm using the ONT-API (Java) for my project in order to manage OWLOntologies and SPARQL Queries.

My issue is : the new class that should be added to the "modelInput" is not inserted.

Here's my code :

```
package test.model;

import com.github.owlcs.ontapi.OntManagers;
import com.github.owlcs.ontapi.Ontology;
import org.apache.jena.atlas.lib.StrUtils;

import org.apache.jena.query.*;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.update.*;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestDatasetAxiomMigration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyCreationException, OWLOntologyStorageException {
    
    OWLOntologyManager manager = OntManagers.createONT();
    OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology(IRI.create("http://ontology/"));
    ontology.addAxiom(factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(factory.getOWLClass("first-class"), factory.getOWLThing()));

    Model modelInput = ((Ontology)ontology).asGraphModel();
    modelA.createResource("second-class").addProperty(RDFS.subClassOf, modelA.createResource("first-class"));

    Dataset dataset = DatasetFactory.create();
    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE) ;
    dataset.addNamedModel("http://ontology/",modelInput);


        // ... perform a SPARQL Update
        GraphStore graphStore = GraphStoreFactory.create(dataset) ;
        String sparqlUpdateString = StrUtils.strjoinNL(
                "PREFIX ont: <http://ontology/>",
                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>",
                "INSERT DATA { ont:University a rdfs:Class } "
        ) ;

        UpdateAction.parseExecute(sparqlUpdateString,dataset);
        dataset.commit() ;

        Model modelOut = dataset.getNamedModel("http://ontology/");

        System.out.print("Size: "+modelInput.size()+" ; "+modelOut.size());
    }
}
```

As we trigger the execution, the "modelInput" is not updated : the change is not committed to the model ; the modelOutput has the same size as the "modelInput".
I can't understand where I'm doing wrong as I have no errors.

Thank you for your help.

NB: This small sample below doesn't reveal the complexity of the hole project.
By the way, I'm using the dataset object because I'm planning copying some axioms from one ontology to another with a SPARQL query.

Comment: you insert the data into the default graph, but you check if it's in the named model. That's a mismatch. Either do `INSERT DATA{ GRAPH <http://ontology/> { ont:University a rdfs:Class } }` or `UpdateAction.parseExecute(sparqlUpdateString, modelInput);`

Comment: Thank you @UninformedUser for your quick reply. 
You're totally right about the mismatch. It finally worked. 

Going further with my SPARQL Query, I would like to implement an 
```
PREFIX ont: <http://ontology/>
INSERT {
GRAPH <http://ontology/>{
ont:University rdf:type rdfs:Class .
}
}
WHERE
{ GRAPH <http://ontology/>
{ 
    <first-class> rdf:type  rdfs:Class
}
}
```

According to http://www.sparql.org/validate/update the query seems to be syntactically correct but nothing is committed. I can't see why.

Comment: what would be the purpose of that query?I mean, in the `WHERE` part you do not bind a value to any variable and in the `INSERT` part you add a static triple. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve here? Or in general maybe?

Comment: I'm sure nothing is committed because there is no binding in the `WHERE` part, thus, the `INSERT` part isn't "triggered". Why not using `INSERT DATA` again?

Comment: My bad. You're completely right. I forgot to bind a value in the WHERE with the INSERT part.
Thank you again for your help.